# WPF application with Entity Framework, proper settings for app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have a WPF program that uses Entity Framework (DB first approach). It works fine on my development laptop, but it crashes right at the beginning on the other computers and it's obviously because it some how can not connect to DB.

But about the very root of the problem, I read many things online, and although I don't have any certain answer but it seems like it has something to do with the connection string and `app.config` in general.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on my development laptop and I've installed Microsoft SQL Server on the test unit.

The whole scenario is that I want to publish my application and any user can download and install it easily.

Here is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory 
              type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
             <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AssetManagementDBEntities"
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.AssetManagementDBModel.csdl|res://*/Entity.AssetManagementDBModel.ssdl|res://*/Entity.AssetManagementDBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;initial catalog=AssetManagementDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Also I have to say, I couldn't find the `.dll` file that `csdl`, `ssdl` and `msl` must be in that!

The "Build Action" of the `.edmx` file is set to `EntityDeploy`

Comment: can you show your connection string in appconfig?

Comment: What I cannot see in your connection string is `data source=SQLSERVERLOCATION;` It should be inside the &quoted section. As to value it depends on installation of sql server use whatever is Management Studio displaying as you login in `server name` text box value might be different on your computers.

Comment: But it works fine on my laptop. And on the other computers it's probably different, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe you are using a local database that exists on your laptop, but not on the other computers.

Comment: Yes, I use a local DB. And I want the program to create the file on the computer if it does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution my self:

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx), it's not possible with DB-first approach, because it tries to initialize the model each time, and therefore it needs the DB to exist. So I just copied the classes and files that was created based on my DB and use them like code-first approach (the above link explained it very well). Note that you should remove the `ConnectionString` totally, because as it's explained in that link, the DB context takes care of that.

**Note that you have to have SQLEXPRESS or LocalDB on your machine** (if you have installed Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 then one of them is already installed).

Now when the program runs for the first time, it creates DB file in `C:\users\[your_user_name]` (there should be 2 files, the main DB file and the `log` file).

Leave a comment if you have questions about details